# Custom validator for email doesn't throw exception when validating an invalid email address on a Spatie DTO object

Tags: php, dto, php-attributes

I'm currently working on an integration with a third party API for an application, for which I'm using [Spatie's data transfer object library](https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object). I'm currently looking to set up validation for some fields, and have run into an issue.

I've written the following validator attribute, to validate that a string contains an email address:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Integrations\Foo\Data\Validators;

use Attribute;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Validation\ValidationResult;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Validator;

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_PROPERTY | Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE)]
final class ValidEmail implements Validator
{
    public function validate(mixed $value): ValidationResult
    {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return ValidationResult::valid();
        }
        return ValidationResult::invalid("Value should be a valid email address");
    }
}
```

And it's used in this DTO implementation:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Integrations\Foo\Data;

use App\Http\Integrations\Foo\Data\Validators\ValidEmail;
use Carbon\CarbonImmutable;

/**
 * DTO class for a child in the birthday request results
 *
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
final class ChildBirthday extends DTO
{
    #[ValidEmail]
    public readonly string $email;

    public readonly CarbonImmutable $dob;

    public readonly bool $purchased;

    public function __construct(string $email, string $dob, bool $purchased)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->dob = CarbonImmutable::parse($dob);
        $this->purchased = $purchased;
    }

    public static function fromResponseItem(string $email, string $dob, bool $purchased): self
    {
        return new static($email, $dob, $purchased);
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

NB: The DTO class extends my own bespoke DTO base class, but that is relatively simple - it just extends the Spatie one to apply strict mode, set a default cast for `CarbonImmutable` and set the `psalm-immutable` and `psalm-seal-properties` annotations.

I've also written a Pest test for it:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Integrations\Foo\Data;

use App\Http\Integrations\Foo\Data\ChildBirthday;
use Carbon\CarbonImmutable;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Exceptions\ValidationException;

use function Pest\Faker\faker;

it('throws an error if the email is not valid', function () {
    ChildBirthday::fromResponseItem(
        email: 'invalid',
        dob: faker()->date(),
        purchased: faker()->boolean()
    );
})->throws(ValidationException::class);
```

However, the test fails to throw the required exception. Instantiating the class manually with an invalid email address also doesn't throw the exception.

My validation attribute looks broadly consistent with [the example given in the documentation](https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object#validation), but this is actually the first time I've used PHP 8 attributes, so I'm wondering if there's something I've got wrong about the syntax. I've tried setting a breakpoint in the attribute with PsySh and it never triggers when populating a new instance of the DTO in Laravel Tinker, so it looks like it's never calling the attribute in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It's due to my setting a constructor in the DTO class - it's fine to set a named constructor as I have done, but not the `__construct()` method. Removing the constructor method resolves the issue.